# How to do a one-to-many or many-to-many subdatasheet in ms access?

Tags: ms-access, many-to-many, one-to-many

I'm new here so thanks for any advice or help. I'm working with an access database problem that involves two different tables. One table is individual clients, and the other is corporate clients. Many of our corporate clients are owned by our individual clients, and many of our individual clients have ownership in more than one corporation. I am trying to create a subdatasheet that allows me to demonstrate these relationships, but I am running into trouble with the corporations that are owned by multiple people and the people that have ownership in multiple corps.

If a subdatasheet is the wrong direction to move toward, what should I do instead?

The relevant field in the Individual table is "Client ID", and the relevant fields in the Corporate field are "Client Name" and "Owner ID", which indicates the Client ID(s) of the owner(s).

Sorry if my explanation was confusing but I am new to access and programming in general. Let me know if any more info would help.

thanks

Edit: I've been working on making a relationship table to host the many-to-many relationship. The links are the "Client ID" column from the Individual table and the "Client Name" column from the Corporate table. That said, I still haven't figured out how to do this.

Edit: Alright I'll try to paint you a picture here. So the Individual Table has relevant field "Client ID" as well as other basic information such as first and last name, phone number, etc. The Individual table also has a "Client #" field, but this field is used to identify individual as well as corporate clients, so I figured that I needed to create another unique, identifying field for my individual clients (Client ID).

The Corporate Table has relevant information "Client Name" (which serves as the unique identifier for each client) and "Individual ID" (which is a mostly blank field that I just created in order to link the two different tables together. The purpose of this "Individual ID" field is to indicate which individual(s) own which business(es), and which businesses are owned by which individuals. It also has basic info fields such as address and phone number.

I am realizing now that a subdatasheet probably will not do what I need it to, so ideally, I would like something (perhaps a multivalued field) that shows these possible connections between individual clients that we work for, as well as the businesses that we do work for (completely unrelated from the owners). Not all individual clients own businesses and not all businesses are owned by our individual clients. This is to help with organization purposes. Right now I have two different tables, one for individual clients and one for corporate/business clients. They aren't related in any way. I would like a multivalued field, query, etc that can connect the two different types of clients where needed. I am also having trouble entering in the data for multiple connections (when a company has more than one owner).

Edit2: alright so I think I understand now. The junction table should essentially auto-fill the related data from the 'Individuals' and 'Corporate' tables? If I'm understanding that correctly, then would this method work? Each Individual is identified by a unique number, and each Corp is identified by its name. Then, in the Corp table, I can add a multivalued field that draws data from the Individual-identifying number (IIN). When these fields are populated with the IIN(s), the junction table should display the correct many-to-many relationships? Yes?

Comment: For the task you are having difficulty with, are there ONLY these two tables for THIS task? If so, and if I understand correctly, this will not work. I believe you need a relationship table that can be used to define the role(s) between the two tables. i.e. Many INDIVIDUALS related to one CORPORATE or one INDIVIDUAL related to many CORPORATE. Is there more to this?

Comment: This *should* be possible, but no one could really tell you how to structure such a table/query without more information about the data itself. If you could create some example data of the tables and an example of what you're looking for in a final result, we *should* be able to help.

Comment: @WayneG.Dunn I've edited the original question.

Comment: @Jiggles32 I've edited the original question

Comment: So, if I am understanding your prediciment correctly, you want to fill in the `Individual ID`. But, what will it be based on exactly, if you have no link between the two tables? Are the `Client Name` on `Individual` and `Corprorate` Tables the same, if so can you link the tables that way? This is really all a matter of interpreting the data in question.

Comment: You have table 'Individuals' and you have table 'Corporate'. In reality you can have multiple Individuals 'own' a 'Corporation', thus you have only one choice, which is to create a 'Owners' table that links your two tables together. i.e. create this table with two fields: Individual key and Corporate Key and make those the PK for your new table. Then link the existing tables to the new table using those fields. Finally, add 'Owners' records as needed to match your ownership's. Yes, this will require a structure change and may be a pain, but it is the best way to do it.

Comment: @WayneG.Dunn yes, but some individuals also have ownership in more than one corporation. Would your solution still work? And if so, I'm confused about how the relationship data would be presented. Would I have to go to the new 'Owners' table to see these relationships? Or is there a way to show the connections in both the Individuals and Corporate tables? Many thanks for your help

Comment: question has been updated

Comment: Create the 'Owners' table, have the PK a compound of fields 'ClientID' and 'ClientName". To have multiple owners of a CORP simply save as many 'Owner' recs as needed using the unique ClientID and same ClientName. To get a list of all owners, retrieve all of the 'CORP' records, plus RIGHT Join ‘Owner’ (in case there are no related Individuals.  Is there enough similarity between Individual and Corporate tables to just use one table to serve both?

Comment: @WayneG.Dunn figured it out. Thank you for your help